# Help posting to users feeds

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have an app and I want to post to the users feed.

All the users have allowed publish_stream permission but I have no idea how to post to their feeds which I should be able to do even if the user is offline.

I want to use curl and the graph like this:

curl -F 'access_token=...' \
     -F 'message=Hello, Arjun. I like this new API.' \
     https://graph.facebook.com/arjun/feed

Do I simply use the access code I got when the users initially allowed me access, or do I have to get a new access code each time I want to post to their feed, if so, how do I do that?

Any help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the user authorized your application you get an access-token from facebook. You can use this token to post to the users-wall until he changes his password or removes your application from his application list.

I think you need to include your api-key in the request. Otherwise please provide the error message your getting!